# Hadoop , error while trying to add mapper class

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins, hadoop2

I have successfully installed the **Hadoop Plugins** . And i am able to access the **DFS** locations as well from eclipse . But when i tried adding a Mapper or reducer class to the project that i created am getting the following error

**Superclass cannot be parameterized unless source level is 1.5.**

I checked the build path locations and all Hadoop jars are available..
What might be the error ?

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with Hadoop. It is about your JDK version.
Check the installed JDK version on your system. And check also the project configuration (if there is any).
Maybe if there a configuration for the project, it is set to source level < 1.5